# Typescript, Como buscar 2 o 3 palabras dentro de un string sin importar el orden de las palabras en la búsqueda

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Quiero que mi buscador encuentre resultados sin importar el orden en el que se escriben los términos de búsqueda.

Ejemplo actualmente Si busco "coche color rojo" me encuentra todos los resultados que contengan "coche color rojo" Pero si busco "coche rojo" o " rojo coche" no encuentra nada.

Como podría hacer para que me arroje resultados buscando sin importar el orden pero si las coincidencias?

Mi código:

```
const filteredUsuarios = (): Usuario[] => {

        if(search.length === 0 )
            return usuarios.slice(currentPage, currentPage + 50);         

        // Busqueda

        const filtered = usuarios.filter( 
            user => user.name.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,"").includes( search ) || 
            user.identityNumber.includes( search )  
        );

        return filtered.slice(currentPage, currentPage + 50);

    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo luce un usuario? ¿Qué hace `normalize` y que significa `NFD`? ¿De dónde sale `search` que aparece como por arte de magia? ¿Qué estás remplazando?  ¿Qué es `currentPage, currentPage + 50`? Nada de lo que adjuntas parece tener que ver con lo que preguntas y solo parecen pedazos de algo más grande que es irrelevante a tu pregunta. Por favor, adjunta un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en el que se pueda ver tu problema. Algo con un texto , que refleje tu planteamiento de "coche color rojo".

Comment: Considero que la pregunta tiene los elementos suficientes para hacer una réplica sin necesidad de postear el componente completo. [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ampliar tu normalización de caracteres agregando un `trim()` (Por los espacios al inicio y al final) Y un `toLowerCase()` para asegurar la búsqueda.
Partí el nombre en pedacitos y luego verifiqué con [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) si habían coincidencias. Al final tuve que usar un `filter()` para quitarme los `undefined` que intentaba castear el `map()`

Te dejo un snippet con la funcionalidad, intenta manipulando la variable `search`. Lo hice en JS puro ya que el snippet no acepta TS, pero no te será complicado traducirlo.

```js
const normalize = ( text ) => {
    return `${text}`
    .trim()
    .normalize("NFD")
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .toLowerCase()
}

const search = 'sáNCHez';
const names = ['Rodrigo Nájera', 'Edwin Sánchez', 'Heriberto Gonzalez', 'Santiago Sámano', 'Roberto Sánchez'];
const filtered = names
.map( name => {
  const originalName = name;
  const _name = normalize(name).split(' ');
  const _search = normalize(search).split(' ');
  if( _search.some( piece => _name.includes(piece) ) ) {
    return originalName;
  } 
})
.filter( name => name !== undefined )
console.log(filtered);
```